# Disabled seekBar without dimming

Tags: android, seekbar

I need to prevent seekbar from user inputs in special cases. If I use `setEnabled(false)` it becomes gray instead of white.

Is there any method to disable seekbar without dimming or set another drawable for progress in disabled seekbar ?

Comment: can you please share how to solved it

Comment: sorry, cant remember how it was implemented since it was 4 years ago, but most probably I've extended seekbar and override onTouchEvent method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to change this, and I don't believe it's good practice to override the visual queue for a user that something is disabled. If it looks active, but doesn't interact, I'm going to be mad at your app.

Regardless, to answer your question, you should look at [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598638/changing-progress-drawable-of-seekbar-programatically) outlines it specifically for seek bars.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It is possible! But you need to override SeekBar's drawableStateChanged function, with something like this:

```
@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    final Drawable progressDrawable = getProgressDrawable();
    if(isEnabled() == false && progressDrawable != null) progressDrawable.setAlpha(255);
}
```

Actually I was very angry, when I saw hardcoded alpha value in AbsSeekBar:

```
mDisabledAlpha = a.getFloat(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Theme_disabledAlpha, 0.5f);
```

Because there is no function, which will turn off, or even change disabled alpha value for SeekBar. Just take a look at those lines of code in drawableStateChanged function:

```
if (progressDrawable != null) {
    progressDrawable.setAlpha(isEnabled() ? NO_ALPHA : (int) (NO_ALPHA * mDisabledAlpha));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Better solution here....

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setEnabled(false)` and set the `Theme_disabledAlpha` attribute as @Ilya Pikin mentioned above like this:

```
<item name="android:disabledAlpha">1.0</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Android changes alpha value of color to 127 from 255 in disabled state. Just make sure you set it back to 255 after disabling seekbar.

```
seekBar.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setAlpha(255);
    }
});
```

view.post is required only if you are unsure that seekbar is rendered yet or not, otherwise just

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setAlpha(255);
```

is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I´m a bit late to the party, but here is a solution to solve your question.

First of all I recommand to use com.google.android.material.slider.Slider nowadays. It is much more flexible than the old seekbar was. To do so, use the following import in your gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0' //1.4.0 or newer
```

Now create your layout file, let´s it call layout_slider

e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/sbSize"
        style="@style/sliderTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:value="25"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="100.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now open your styles.xml file and create the sliderTheme. It should look like this:

```
<style name="sliderTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Slider">
    <item name="trackColorInactive">@color/slider_track_inactive</item>
    <item name="thumbColor">@color/slider_thumb_color</item>
    <item name="trackColorActive">@color/slider_track_active</item>
</style>
```

The next step we need to do is create a new Resource Directory named color inside the res folder. (Resource type is color)

Now create a file to change the trackColor for active and inactive state. Let´s name it slider_track_inactive.xml

Copy the following content inside that file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0.24" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

the first value is for the active and the second is for the inactive color. Change alpha and color to a value to want. All my sample values are the Google default values.

Now create a file called slider_thumb_color.xml inside the color folder. It should look like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Again, change these values as you want.
Last, create a file called slider_track_active.xml inside the color folder. It should look like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.32" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Now you have customized all colors for the disabled slider. There are much more values you can customize with the same technique. All default keys you can customize inside your styles.xml file are:

```
<item name="haloColor">@color/material_slider_halo_color</item>
<item name="haloRadius">@dimen/mtrl_slider_halo_radius</item>
<item name="labelStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Tooltip</item>
<item name="thumbColor">@color/material_slider_thumb_color</item>
<item name="thumbElevation">@dimen/mtrl_slider_thumb_elevation</item>
<item name="thumbRadius">@dimen/mtrl_slider_thumb_radius</item>
<item name="tickColorActive">@color/material_slider_active_tick_marks_color</item>
<item name="tickColorInactive">@color/material_slider_inactive_tick_marks_color</item>
<item name="trackColorActive">@color/material_slider_active_track_color</item>
<item name="trackColorInactive">@color/material_slider_inactive_track_color</item>
<item name="trackHeight">@dimen/mtrl_slider_track_height</item>
<item name="minSeparation">0dp</item>
```