# How to set seekbar disable without dimming in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have struck with one problem how can i disable seekbar without dimming, i have tried all the method in this question which have a same doubt 
[android disabled seekBar without dimming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14481832/5498065)  let me post what i have tried so far:

I have set

```
private SeekBar seekBar;
seekBar=(SeekBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.seek); 
seekBar.setEnabled(false);
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setAlpha(255);
```

in xml:

```
 <SeekBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/mode"
                    android:maxHeight="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/seek"
                    />
```

Still this code doesn't make my seekbar brighter can anyone help me Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `seekbar` is different from `seekBar2`. Shouldn't you use same seekbar? As a workaround you can set empty onTouchListener, which will return always true to the seekbar.

Comment: sorry @VladMatvienko i have changed

Comment: same thing - `seekbar` is not `seekBar`. Please show your actual code. Because for me this themes as the reason of your problem - you use different seekbars.

Comment: this is what i have done i need to disable seekbar without dimming how it is possible

Comment: you code won't compile. You use 2 different variables - one is `seekbar`, the other is `seekBar`. you init only `seekBar` : `seekBar=(SeekBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.seek); `, but use `seekbar`

Comment: your code is still not compilable. There is no method `enable(boolean)`. **Please post your real code.** I'm tired of asking that already.

Comment: am really soryy @VladMatvienko check it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android disabled seekBar without dimming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481832/android-disabled-seekbar-without-dimming)

Comment: i have said already i tried all the method still not get worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it works for me.

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: and one more thing i need to make my seekbar touchable this will make my seekbar not touchable

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a touch event will continue down the `View` hierarchy (to views behind one another) until the last layer, unless it is suppressed by a `return true` along the way. Thus, if we return `true` within that code below, the touch event will stop and `SeekBar` will not be seekable. If you want your `View` to work again, you can return `false` in your touch event.

```
boolean isSeekable; //true = enable, false =  disable

seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return !isSeekable;
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43512053/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: sorry i was impolite. i has add some explain on it